# Viewswitching and areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do I use the Viewswitcher function of mvc 4 when I am using areas?

If I don't but a new ViewSwitcherController.cs in each area then I get areas about the route when I try to invoke the viewswitcher and I am in an area.

If I do put the viewSwitcherContoller in the area then I get errors about multiple controllers with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being ignorant. The solution is to specify the area in the viewswitcher view.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Mobile view", "SwitchView", "ViewSwitcher", new { area="",
```

since there is no area I just used **""** which is worked for me.